# Mybatis Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 190

Tags: java, mybatis

I am trying to retrieve values from DB, but I can't able to get all the values. I am getting `TooManyResultsException`.

**MapperInterface**

This is the mapper interface which I am invoking.

```
public interface ITranslatorDAO
{
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> translate();
}
```

**mapper.xml**

This part is the SQL which i am running against DB and it has 190 rows.i wanted to retrieve all rows but it is throwing exception as i mentioned below.

```
<select id="translate"  resultType="map">
    SELECT
        section,
        data,
        translation
    FROM
        web_data..wd_ofx_translate
    ORDER BY
        section,
        data,
        translation
</select>
```

**Exception traceback**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: 
    nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.TooManyResultsException: 
    Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 190
```

Comment: your query returned 190 rows.  consider the WHERE clause

Answer (score 6):

you should add @MapKey to tell mybatis which column in table you want as the key of the map, such as use section column as key of the map :

```
public interface ITranslatorDAO{
        @MapKey("section") 
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> translate();
}
```

Answer (score -5):

The selectOne() method is used when you want to run a query that **selects one** row.  If you want to select more than one row, use a different method.

Comment: What method can i use?? can you please tell me

Comment: here is a magical site that contains mybatis information: http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/