# How to count rows and get result as Map using MyBatis?

Tags: java, mybatis

im struggling with a problem described in title. This is query:

```
select state, count(state) from orders group by state;
```

and i want to get the result as a `Map<String, Long>` How can i achieve it using myBatis? Im using xml mapper. Already tried to use `resultType="hashmap"` and get this exception

> TooManyResultsException: Expected one result (or null) to be returned
>   by selectOne(), but found: 3

after using like here [stack sollution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34666152/mybatis-expected-one-result-or-null-to-be-returned-by-selectone-but-found) `@MapKey("state")`  get this exception

> JsonGenerationException: Null key for a Map not allowed in JSON (use a converting NullKeySerializer?)

which i dont understand because state is filled in every record

Any suggestion what im doing wrong and how to do it right?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `@MapKey("state")` then return type of the function would be `Map<String, Map<String, Object>>` where for each `state` value the map for the record is returned.

In that record map keys are column names. In you query there's unnamed column which causes this issue. Change you query to something like this:

```
select state, count(state) cnt from orders group by state;
```